# Where to find Historical price data (csv preferable) for global Gov bonds and markets. All dollar denominated?

Tags: bond, backtesting, historical-data, excel, european

I'm doing a lengthy backtest on a certain portfolio and i've managed to get FTSE 100 data going back to 05-30-1990, where could I find data for global Government bonds going back to that date?

A csv would be best as I need to import it into excel ( would be a cake walk in python or R :( ).

Many thanks!

Comment: What are "global bonds/markets"? Govys? Corporates?

Comment: Govys! i'll edit this!

Comment: When you say "price data", what is it you're looking for? Prices for specific issues, or - say - total return series for benchmarks?

Comment: Historical daily or monthly quotes.

Comment: But quotes on what? All outstanding govys for all countries of interest back to 1990?

Comment: IMHO total return index for some fairly wide class of govt debt would be best for this kind of backtesting. No need to go down to individual country level.

Comment: Yea that's what i'm thinking. But where can you find a total return index like that going back to 1990? From my forays into yahoo finance I haven't been able to find much going back that far.